# Can I allocate 'free space' on my harddrive to a partition?

Tags: partitioning

During 10.10 installation I deleted a 30GB partition and changed it to a 2GB swap, and then reinstalled Ubuntu over partition two (where 10.04 was). I have a third large partition where most of my files are.

How do I allocate the newly freed up 28GB or so from the first partition and allocate it to the third partition?

Answer (score 2):

You can boot up into a LiveCD and use GParted to expand the third partition. You should make sure to back up your files before this in case something goes wrong, but it should expand the partition properly, and you will have an extra 28GB of space.

Comment: Thanks. Would it work if the free space is on the 'other side' of my Ubuntu install from the third partition?

Comment: If it's on the other side, it will require two operations. You'll need to first move the Ubuntu partition over so the free space is by the partition you want to enlarge, then expand that partition.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm , i think it could be done by using GParted but , it requires to delete both drives , where it will merge become 1 partition and format it .

Comment: Thanks. However, would really like to be able to achieve this without having to format the partition..